# sharepoint online copy document with term value javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using below command using JavaScript to copy a document in the same site in SharePoint Online. The file is copied successfully, but the associated metadata term values selected from my term set is not getting copied.

I am getting:

```
_sourceFile = this.currentItem.get_file();
```

And then later I am doing:

```
_sourceFile.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);
```

File is copied but not term values.

Can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an example [here](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sp2016-o365-sp-movecopyutil-javascript-copy-move-files-and-folder) that is copying files between libraries:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.MoveCopyUtil.copyFile(context,"http://sp2016/sitepages/home.aspx","http://sp2016/sitepages/home1.aspx");
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){},function(){});
```

It claims to copy the metadata as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same behavior as with CopyTo, it only copies metadata with datatype Text, Datetime, Lookup, etc - not Managed Metadata term values from term set.

Comment: That's a pity. Out of curiosity, does it work when you use the interface to "Sent To" another location? Click on the file in the library and select the Documents tab. Locate "Send To", and select "Other Location" from the dropdown. I understand you're trying to programmatically achieve this, but if it works through the interface then I'm sure there must be a way to do it with code.

Comment: Yes, the "Send to > Copy" in the ribbon Files tab works for all metadata, including term values.